# Is an Android ContentProvider absolutely necessary for syncing?

Tags: android, database, rest, synchronization, android-contentprovider

I am trying to write an application that synchronises data stored locally on an Android phone with data stored on a remote database on a server elsewhere. Of course, there will be an UI screen available on the phone where the user can view/edit the data.

I have decided to do the syncing via a RESTful web service and have watched the Google I/0 2010 video that explains 3 various design patterns for creating an Android REST client. They all have one component in common - a Content Provider.

I was wondering if it is absolutely necessary to create a Content Provider for accessing the  data as I will only be accessing it within my application, or is it necessary because the synchronisation code will need to run in its own process?.

Thank you for your help!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not necessary to use a content provider. You can write a class that retrieves data from a server and run this process in a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Keep in mind that the retrieval of data should never lock your UI.